# Помощь в разборке массива

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть такой массив -

```
{
  "result":{
    "ID":"238",
    "ENTITY_ID":"CRM_LEAD",
    "FIELD_NAME":"UF_CRM_1512040228",
    "USER_TYPE_ID":"enumeration",
    "XML_ID":null,
    "SORT":"100",
    "MULTIPLE":"Y",
    "MANDATORY":"N",
    "SHOW_FILTER":"E",
    "SHOW_IN_LIST":"Y",
    "EDIT_IN_LIST":"Y",
    "IS_SEARCHABLE":"N",
    "SETTINGS":{
      "DISPLAY":"CHECKBOX",
      "LIST_HEIGHT":1,
      "CAPTION_NO_VALUE":""
    },
    "EDIT_FORM_LABEL":{
      "en":"\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0443\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u043e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043a\u0442",
      "ru":"\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0443\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u043e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043a\u0442"
    },
    "LIST_COLUMN_LABEL":{
      "en":"\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0443\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u043e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043a\u0442",
      "ru":"\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0443\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u043e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043a\u0442"
    },
    "LIST_FILTER_LABEL":{
      "en":"\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0443\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u043e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043a\u0442",
      "ru":"\u0418\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u0443\u0435\u043c\u044b\u0439 \u043e\u0431\u044a\u0435\u043a\u0442"
    },
    "ERROR_MESSAGE":{
      "en":null,
      "ru":null
    },
    "HELP_MESSAGE":{
      "en":null,
      "ru":null
    },
    "LIST":[
      {
        "ID":"126",
        "SORT":"10",
        "VALUE":"\u041d\u0435\u0438\u0437\u0432\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043d\u043e",
        "DEF":"N"
      },
      {
        "ID":"123",
        "SORT":"20",
        "VALUE":"Center",
        "DEF":"N"
      },
      {
        "ID":"124",
        "SORT":"30",
        "VALUE":"City Lake",
        "DEF":"N"
      },
      {
        "ID":"125",
        "SORT":"40",
        "VALUE":"Villaggo",
        "DEF":"N"
      },
      {
        "ID":"140",
        "SORT":"50",
        "VALUE":"\u0413\u043e\u0440\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0447\u0438",
        "DEF":"N"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

в конце есть `"LIST":` как мне постучаться и сказать ему: "Эй, массив, у меня есть ID 125, дай-ка мне его значение VALUE"

Comment: Парсить. Либо мапить json на класс, и и работать как с коллекцией объектов.

Comment: Вам тоже кажется, что это json?

Comment: `json_decode` + `array_filter`

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, перебрать значения

```
$value = null;

$result = json_decode($json); // в $json текст из вашего примера

foreach($result->result->LIST as $item)
{
    if($item->ID == 125)
        $value = $item->VALUE; // нужное значение будет в $value
}
```

Comment: А если значений 10.000 к примеру?

Comment: foreach быстрее чем array_filter и array_map

Comment: Сравнительный тест скорости циклов и array_map/filter: http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/

Comment: а на пхп 7 тестировали скорость?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы реализовал всё в виде небольшой функции:

```
function findListValue(string $json, int $id) {
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    if (!array_key_exists('result', $data)) {
        return null;
    }

    $list = array_values(array_filter($data['result']['LIST'], function ($value) use ($id) {
        return $value['ID'] == $id;
    }));

    if (empty($list)) {
        return null;
    }

    return $list[0]['VALUE'];
}

$json = 'ваш json';
var_dump(findListValue($json, 125));
```

Проверки можно убрать или добавить, но пример должен работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $json = ваш "массив";
    $decoded = json_decode($json);
    $list = $decoded->result->LIST;
    $iNeedThis;       
    foreach ($list as $item) {
        if ($item->ID == "125") {
            $iNeedThis = $item;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Про array_filter повторяться не буду, т.к. и в комментарии писал, и ответ с его использованием тоже дан.

Если же вы уверены, что значения ID не могут повторяться, то вот еще пара вариантов в копилку:

```
$arr = json_decode($str, 1);
$id = 125; // Требуемый ID

// Вариант с array_reduce()
$item = array_reduce($arr['result']['LIST'], function($carry, $item) use($id){
    return $item['ID'] == $id ? $item['VALUE'] : $carry;
}, false);
echo $item; // На выходе - Нужное значение || false

// Вариант с array_column()
// Собираем всё в массив, где ключами будут значения ID, а значениями - VALUE 
$data = array_column($arr['result']['LIST'], 'VALUE', 'ID');
echo isset($data[$id]) ? $data[$id] : false;
```